# How to delete an element (item) from RecyclerView, using its checkBox?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I make my own ToDo Android App, using RecyclerView. Every its item is a CardView with checkBox. App adds new elements well, but my removal algorithm doesn't work.

Here's adapter's code:

```
package com.myapps.mytodolist

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.myapps.mytodolist.databinding.TodoItemBinding

class ToDoAdapter(val remover: Remover): RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoAdapter.ToDoHolder>() {
    var todoList = ArrayList<ToDo>()
    class ToDoHolder(item: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        val binding=TodoItemBinding.bind(item)
        fun bind(todo: ToDo, remover: Remover)=with(binding){
            checkBox.text=todo.todoTitle
            if (checkBox.isChecked){
                remover.remove(todo)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ToDoHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.todo_item, parent, false)
        return ToDoHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todoList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ToDoHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(todoList[position], remover)
    }

    fun addToDo(todo: ToDo){
        todoList.add(todo)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeToDo(todo: ToDo){
        todoList.remove(todo)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    interface Remover{
        fun remove(todo: ToDo)
    }

}
```

I created the function "RemoveToDo" to remove the element from ToDoList, interface "Remover", and override the function "Remove" in MainActivity(the elements is added in TaskActivity and imported here):

```
package com.myapps.mytodolist

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.myapps.mytodolist.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ToDoAdapter.Remover {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val adapter = ToDoAdapter(this)
    private var taskLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>?=null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        init()
        taskLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
            if(it.resultCode== RESULT_OK){
                adapter.addToDo(it.data?.getSerializableExtra("todo") as ToDo)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun init(){
        binding.apply{
            recView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            recView.adapter = adapter
            buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
                taskLauncher?.launch(Intent(this@MainActivity, TaskActivity::class.java))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun remove(todo: ToDo) {
        adapter.removeToDo(todo)
    }
}
```

So, what did I do wrong? Why my adapter doesn't remove items from RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't set `OnCheckedChangeListener` , you will not get event of check change of checkbox so your `remove` will never be called so set code in your viewholder something like this

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked -> 
            if(isChecked){
                remover.remove(todo)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't actually remove the item *when you click the checkbox*. It removes the item *when it's being bound to a `ViewHolder` for display*, and it does that **if the checkbox in the reusable `ViewHolder` is currently checked**.

What that means is, if you have a pool of 6 `ViewHolder`s that are being recycled to display your list items, and you check the box in one of them, as you scroll the list **every 6th item will reuse that VH, which has a checked box, which will delete the todo when you examine its checked state**.

You need to add a listener that fires when the user interacts with the checkbox instead. You can use an `OnCheckedChangeListener` like in *jayesh*'s answer, or you could use an `OnClickListener` as normal. Personally I prefer the click listener, which only fires when the user taps the `CheckBox`, and not when you set its state (which you often need to do in a `RecyclerView` since you're reusing `ViewHolder`s and updating their Views to display different items' states). You can do that like this:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener { remover.remove(todo) }
```

Or you can set it up once when initialising the `ViewHolder` instead of every time you bind to it, and make it get the current adapter position (the `position` it's displaying) and grab the *todo* item in the adapter list.